# Task.WaitAll returns before all tasks have completed

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

`WaitAll` not working. I get **Done** before tasks are completed.

I have some groups. each group contains items i want each item to be processed in a separate task.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    List<Task> TaskList = new List<Task>();
    foreach (string group in groups)
    {
        Task task = new Task(() => { scan_group(group, timeout); });
        task.Start();
        TaskList.Add(task);
    }

    Task.WaitAll(TaskList.ToArray());
    Console.WriteLine("-  Done !" );
}

public static void scan_group (){
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Parallel.ForEach<string>(items, x =>
    {
        scan(x, y);
    }));
}
```

Comment: Why all this? What *real* prolem are you trying to solve? All this code except the call to `Parallel.ForEach` doesn't serve any useful purpose. There's no reason to create cold tasks, especially when you call Start in the very next line. The `scan_group` method is also  weird - it starts a Task and then discards any reference to it, making it impossible to monitor it. Finally, the call to `Parallel.ForEach` inside another task, just wastes tasks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All your `scan_group` does is start a task without waiting for it to complete, or returning it to be waited for outside.

So you only wait for the internal tasks to be created, you don't wait for them to complete. That's why you get `Done` before your internal tasks run.

If you want to wait for the `scan_group` tasks, return them and store them in the list instead of creating tasks using the task constructor. For example:

```
foreach (string group in groups)
{
    TaskList.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Parallel.ForEach<string>(items, x => scan(x, y))));
}

Task.WaitAll(TaskList.ToArray());
```

---

Note: Using the `Task` constructor directly is almost never the right solution. Also `Task.Run` is preferable to `Task.Factory.StartNew` if you're on .Net 4.5 and above.

Comment: I suspect it's the groups' elements that need parallel processing, which means all the code could be replaced with a simple `Parallel.ForEach` call, eg after the group elements get flattened.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos If the question would have been clearer, I assume it's possible to create a tailor made solution using TPL Dataflow.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are not awaiting any tasks. The `Task.WaitAll` does wait till all your tasks of `scan_group()` are done. Your `scan_group()` method however should be an async task.

Inside this method you can then use `await` on any task you create there. At the moment you are only starting a new task in the `scan_group()` method but you do not await these tasks. This causes the tasks to be started somewhere on another thread but the thread starting it already moves on and ends the method. The calling method sees this as your task being done.

Some implementation:

Declaration of `scan_group()`:

```
public static async Task scan_group() 
{
    // create tasks for your tasks inside this method.
    List<Task> itemTasks = new List<Task>();
    items.foreach(x => itemTasks.Add(scan(x,y));

    await Task.WhenAll(itemTasks.ToArray());
}
```

Your call to `scan_group` would stay the same.